# Google Calendar API Error

Tags: apex, google

I am getting an error when I make a callout to Google Calendar, I could get the access token but when I call the method to insert an event I get this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

This is my code:

```
        String token = get_access_token();
        final PageReference theUrl = new PageReference('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/xxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/events?acccess_token=' + token);

        String body = '';

        JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeFieldName('end');
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField('dateTime', '2017-01-25T12:30:00');
        gen.writeStringField('timeZone', 'America/Lima');
        gen.writeEndObject();
        gen.writeFieldName('start');
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField('dateTime', '2017-01-25T11:30:00');
        gen.writeStringField('timeZone', 'America/Lima');
        gen.writeEndObject();
        gen.writeStringField('summary', 'Test from Salesforce');
        gen.writeFieldName('attendees');
        gen.writeStartArray();
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField('email', 'xxxxxx@xxxx.edu.pe');
        gen.writeStringField('responseStatus', 'needsAction');
        gen.writeStringField('displayName', 'xxxxxxxx');
        gen.writeEndObject();
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField('email', 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com');
        gen.writeStringField('responseStatus', 'accepted');
        gen.writeStringField('displayName', 'xxxxxxxxx');
        gen.writeBooleanField('organizer', true);
        gen.writeBooleanField('self', true);
        gen.writeEndObject();
        gen.writeEndArray();
        gen.writeEndObject();

        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(theUrl.getUrl());
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setTimeout(120000);
        request.setBody(gen.getAsString());        

        HttpResponse response = (new Http()).send(request);
        system.debug('#### getBody' + response.getBody());

public String get_access_token(){

        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        req.setEndpoint('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
        req.setMethod('POST');

        req.setHeader('ContentType','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        String header = '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}';
        String header_encoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(blob.valueof(header));

        String claim_set = '{"iss":"XXXXXXXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"';
        claim_set += ',"scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"';
        claim_set += ',"aud":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"';
        claim_set += ',"exp":"' + datetime.now().addHours(1).getTime()/1000;
        claim_set += '","iat":"' + datetime.now().getTime()/1000 + '"}';

        String claim_set_encoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(blob.valueof(claim_set));

        String signature_encoded = header_encoded + '.' + claim_set_encoded;

        String key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

        blob private_key = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(key);
        signature_encoded = signature_encoded.replaceAll('=','');
        String signature_encoded_url = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(signature_encoded,'UTF-8');
        blob signature_blob = blob.valueof(signature_encoded_url);

        String signature_blob_string = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.sign('RSA-SHA256', signature_blob, private_key));

        String JWT = signature_encoded + '.' + signature_blob_string;

        JWT = JWT.replaceAll('=','');

        String grant_string= 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer';
        req.setBody('grant_type=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(grant_string, 'UTF-8') + '&assertion=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(JWT, 'UTF-8'));
        res = h.send(req);
        String response_debug = res.getBody() +' '+ res.getStatusCode();
        System.debug('Response =' + response_debug );
        if(res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
            while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
                if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'access_token')) {
                    // Move to the value.
                    parser.nextToken();
                    // Return the access_token
                    return parser.getText();
                }
            }
        }
        return 'error';
    }
```

can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things. I was able to get your example working with a service account. Since you're getting the token, I suspect the values you're passing to the service are not being accepted. My suggestion is to use the Google API Explorer to get the correct values.

Firstly, change
`final PageReference theUrl = new PageReference('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/xxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/events?acccess_token=' + token);`

To
`final PageReference theUrl = new PageReference('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events');`

You do need to pass the access token on the query string. This is already being passed as a value in HttpHeader.

Secondly, this is the JSON string I used to create a parameter.

`String body = '{   "description": "Republic Day of India",   "start": {     "date": "2018-01-26",     "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"   },   "end": {     "date": "2018-01-26",     "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"   },   "location": "200 Amphitheatre Dr, Mountain View, CA",   "visibility": "public",   "transparency": "opaque",   "status": "confirmed",   "summary": "India Day Celebrations",   "reminders": {     "useDefault": true   } }';`

The API Explorer I used to test my input is located at
`https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert`